# find random variables with covariance $>0$ and $=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

I am currently studying for an exam and found the following question:

Let $(x)_ {n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables. Can you construct a sequence of random variables such that for the covariance we get $$\sigma(x_k,x_l)\begin{cases} =0&\textrm{if }|k-l|>1\\>0& \textrm{if } |k-l|\leq1\end{cases}$$?

I've tried some sequence but all of them didn't fit. So is there any sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, let $\{u_t\}$ be i.i.d. with zero mean and
$$x_t=u_t+u_{t-1}.$$

Comment: thanks. but what's $E[x_t]$?

Comment: zero (I've edited my response to be specific)

Comment: okay, so $\sigma (x_t,x_t)=E[x_t^2]=E[u_t^2+u_tu_{t-1}+t_{t-1}^2/4]=?$

Comment: You can pick the variance of $u$ to be whatever you want, say 1.  Then the variance of $x_t$ would be 1.25.

Comment: @JPi  I'm having some troubles to verify your answer: Let $E[x_t]=0$ for all $t$. Then $\sigma(x_t,x_{t-m})=E[(x_t-E[x_t])(x_{t-m}-E[x_{t-m}])]=E[x_tx_{t-m}]$ how can you show this equals $=0$ for $m\neq0,1,-1$?

Comment: Expand $x$ in terms of $u$ and then use the fact that the $u$'s are iid mean zero.